# In MQL4 Assigning from a received struct

Tags: mql4

Does somebody know how to assign a value inside a method from a field of a received struct parameter?

```
struct SOME_STRUCT {
   int      someValue;
};

void someFunction(SOME_STRUCT &someStruct) {
    int someValue = someStruct[0].someValue;
}
```

The assignation fails with:

```
‘[‘ array required
```

Comment: I think you should work on int someValue rather on passing the entire struct.. That's more logic! The error message you got is because you're trying to "subscript" something that is not an array but a struct!

Answer (score 1):

I fail in the way passing the array structure. This is correct:

```
void someFunction(SOME_STRUCT &someStruct[])
```